# How do I access functions outside my file

Tags: javascript

My question is how to access functions which have been created in other files.
I have 3 files `checkSelection.js` `polishToEnglish.js` `polishToGerman.js`.

Struct of file 1 is:

```
//some code

function selectOptions() {
    //some code
    if (document.getElementById("Pol2Eng").checked) {
        polishToEnglish(polish2EnglishDictionaryPath, polishExpression);
    } else if (document.getElementById("Pol2Ger").checked) {
        polishToGerman(polish2EnglishDictionaryPath, polish2GermanDictionaryPath, polishExpression);
    } 
    //some code
}
```

The second one is:

```
function polishToEnglish(polish2EnglishDictionaryPath, polishExpression){
    //some code
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState === 4) {
            var lines = xmlhttp.responseText;
            dictionary = lines.split('\n');
            return findTranslation(dictionary, polishExpression);
        }
    };
    //some code
}

function findTranslation(dictionary, word) {
    dictionary.forEach(function(line){
        if(line.includes(word)) {
            result = line.split(';')[1];
        }
    });
    return result;
}
```

And the third one is:

```
function polishToGerman(polish2EnglishDictionaryPath, polish2GermanDictionaryPath, polishExpression) {
    engWord = polishToEnglish(polish2EnglishDictionaryPath, polishExpression);
}
```

The problem is in the third file. `engWord` is displayed as undefined. 
I've tried some solutions like making the functions `window.polishToEnglish = function(...){}`, but with no effect.
Any ideas how to resolve the problem?

Comment: You can use modules `export function...` then at the top of the third `import {funcName} from ./path/to/file`

Comment: Is `engWord` declared anywhere in the scope of the third function? If not, it will be inserted into the global scope when you assign it (`window.engWord` in a browser context).

Comment: @pmkro I've never used modules so that will be kinda difficult to implement.

Comment: @jspcal no, it's not declared anywhere. But even after declaring it, nothing new happens.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution: link to them in the right order. So:

```
<script src="polishToEnglish.js">
<script src="polishToGerman.js">
<script src=checkSelection.js">
```

since `checkSelection` uses declarations from both other files, and `polishToGerman` relies on `polishToEnglish`.

(Better solution would be using some sort of modules, like ES6's `export`-`import`, or CommonJS and `module.exports`-`require`).

Comment: Your first solution doesn't work. I may try to use modules, but I've never used them before.